# Adding children to divs after initial load in Stenciljs

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, stenciljs

I am very new to Stenciljs and my task is to create a Virtualized Table as a web component in stenciljs. 
The approach I am following is to create the row divs initially but want to fill them up with data/ children nodes after the data is received. 
The data can be an API Call. 
I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically add jsx to html nodes with appendChild or something similar.
It would be awesome if I could get any sort of example or reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use JSX at runtime (because it gets transpiled into `h` calls) but you can pass data into your component as a prop and then let the render function dynamically generate JSX from it (because then the dynamic parts will be transpiled as well). Very simplified example:

```js
export class MyTableComponent {
  @Prop() data: string[][];

  render() {
    return (
      <table>
        {data.map(row => (
          <tr>
            {row.map(col => <td>{col}</td>)}
          </tr>
        )}
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

Alternatively you could expose a class method using the `@Method` decorator that takes some data as a prop and appends something to your component.